# what problems can occur styling if div tags, are replaced by asp.panels (in c# code)

Tags: c#, css

what problems can occur styling if div tags, are replaced by asp.panels (in c# code)

i have a sample code which uses pure html,

the css styles are mapped using the ids of the divs.

i would like to replace these divs by panels using c#, yes i will keep the ids same as that in css file.

### question

should i expect any problems in styling because of hidden problems, or hidden styles, or default style of asp panels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are developing on .NET framework 4.0 you can set [ClientIdMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) property to static, so asp.net don't change your Ids.

Otherwise div ids will be affected by the container's id.

**Answer**

There won't be any problems if you set ClientIdMode to static.

Answer (score 2):

An asp.panel is rendered as a div. Once you convert it, what's rendered should be exactly the raw HTML you have now.

So if you keep the ids the same you shouldn't have any problems.